# Change flowScope value with commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've a boolean variable in my `view-state`:

```
<set name="flowScope.render" value="false" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
```

Now i render a `commandButton` with this variable

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Dates"
                            rendered="#{!render}"
                            update="table1,buttons" />
```

Now i want to change the value of the variable with a click on this commandButton. I tried the `setPropertyActionListener`, but it doesn't work:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Dates" rendered="#{!render}" update="table1,buttons">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{render}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I don't find much about how to change the value. So how is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you set the rendered="#{someBean.renderValue}" property, and set the renderValue value with the commandButton ?

Comment: @pantominas I already had it with a Bean property. But the problem is, when more than 1 user is logged in, the value change it for all. So i should use the flowScope which i change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i figured it out.
I must work with `transitions`. In the same `view-state` where the variable is set, there i define two `transitions`:

```
<transition on="rendertrue">
    <set name="flowScope.render" value="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
</transition>
<transition on="renderfalse">
    <set name="flowScope.render" value="false" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
</transition>
```

I don't change the value of the exist variable, i just overwrite it. If this is the best or cleanes solution, i don't know, but it works.
Now i call the specific `transition` with the `action` statement in the `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Date"
                            rendered="#{!render}" update="table1,buttons"
                            action="rendertrue" />
<p:commandButton value="Hide Date"
                            rendered="#{render}" update="table1,buttons"
                            action="renderfalse" />
```